# problem in converting my project from portrait to landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have developed my project in portrait orientation, now I want to set my project orientation in landscape . I have set all xib file's orientation property as landscape and in .plist also I have set all the items of Supported interface orientations as landscape, but when I run my project one view still comes in portrait orientation... in this view i am showing pdf file.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Try setting the frame of that element when the orientation changes

Comment: You mean that all the views should be changed to Landscape orientation provided whatever may be the orientation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you put the following method in you view controller

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i thought may be you have forgotten to put that function, lol, so i answered that

Answer (score 1):

if Landscape use this code

```
(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

if Portrait use this code

```
(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```